# Removing image in HTML that is not in base64 using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

How can i remove img tags that not in base64 like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS..." />
```

Comment: Are you asking how do you translate the base64 into an image?  See the Wikipedia article [data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) for more information.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc no. I want to remove IMG that is not in base64